# Can I play any video/audio as widget in android?

Tags: android, widget

Can I play video/audio as widget in Android?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't because if you backed to the google docs, you will find that those views only that can be included in the widget layout:

- AnalogClock
- Button
- Chronometer
- ImageButton
- ImageView
- ProgressBar
- TextView
- ViewFlipper
- ListView
- GridView
- StackView
- AdapterViewFlipper

Answer (score 0):

No, check the developer.android.com, you will find limit set of controllers that can be used in Widgets